# "However" in a dependent clause

Tags: english-to-german, subordinate-clause

I want so say something like this in English:

> However, if the edge graph is not connected …

I think this is something like:

> Wenn das Diagramm jedoch nicht verbunden ist, …

However, I'm not sure where to put the word "jedoch". I believe it would normally go right after the verb.

Comment: Es ist da, wo Du es hingesetzt hast, richtig. "Connected" ist hier "zusammenhängend".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ich sehe 3 Möglichkeiten:

```
Jedoch, wenn das Diagramm nicht verbunden ist, …


Wenn jedoch das Diagramm nicht verbunden ist, …


Wenn das Diagramm jedoch nicht verbunden ist, …
```

Statt des `jedoch` vorweg würde auch ein `Wie auch immer` funktionieren.

Comment: Manchmal geht auch `aber` oder `allerdings` (nur nicht am Satzanfang).

Comment: Ich denke bei *however* immer zuerst an *allerdings*.

Comment: Was auch geht ist "Ist aber das Diagramm nicht... "